# threejs skinnedMesh not allowing more than a single instance

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

**Problem**

I'm using a threejs `skinnedMesh` via react fiber. I can control the skeleton but I cannot have more than a single instance of my model in a scene. I assume this is because the skinnedMesh assigns the mesh by reference not value (makes sense).

On the other hand I can use a standard `mesh` and can have several instances with different `position` values but then I can't control the skeleton because that feature only works with `skinnedMesh`.

**Question**

How can I create multiple `skinnedMesh` objects, each with its own position value, that all use the same model?

*options so far*

- remove the skeleton and manually model the character's pose in blender (time consuming)
- import the model into memory 6 different times (less optimal)
- attempt to deep clone the skinned mesh object (seems a bit too hacky)

Answer (score 1):

In ThreeJS, SkeletonUtils.clone ( object : Object3D ) should return you a clone of your skinnedmesh.

[Link to the docs of Threejs](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/utils/SkeletonUtils)

But for react-three-fiber, I can't say for sure.

Comment: Hey Adrien, thanks for the answer. I was messing with cloning but had little luck. That said I'm going to give this another shot and will let you know / accept your answer depending on what I can work out.